# Canvas.drawBitmap extremely high cpu consumption

Tags: android, performance

I have a simple Android application which consists of one View, that holds a Gallery widget.
I load up 10 images to the Gallery object upon view creation.

The FPS during the image transitions (when I swipe right for next image, left for previous) is *low* - it's just not smooth.

I've used the Method profiling function built in eclipse to profile the application, and noticed that `Canvas.drawBitmap` consumes a lot of CPU.

I'm currently targeting Android 2.3.3, so `hardwareacceleration` is irrelevant.

Furthermore, downsampling the bitmaps did not change anything - even when downsampling by a large scale.

Currently using Samsung Galaxy TAB

Any insights on this?

Comment: Your gallery is custom? and overriding the onDraw?

Comment: @userSeven7s nope I didn't customize anything - it's a regular Gallery object